# Microsoft Blend 4 Crashes On Splash Screen

Tags: .net-framework, microsoft-expression

Recently I encountered a big problem: Blend 4 always crashes immediately after a splash screen ends. No error numbers mentioned, just a crash window saying "Blend has been crashed, debug or close".

Is anybody else familiar with that problem? I tried to get some help from Google but there were no relevant references.

---

I Clicked "Debug" and JIT Debugger was opened, it threw "FataExecutionEngineError" exception... What does it mean?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a support forum for software, not even programming related software.

Answer (score 0):

Check Event Viewer to see if anything has been logged

Also see the log files if there are any generated (not sure where it is generated but search 
online)

A common way to debug such issues is to attach procmon form sysinternals and then create a filter for expression blend binary, after that launch and let it crash, now look back at procmon and see what it is loading and searching for

If you know windbg, attach the debugger and see the reason for crash

Comment: I Clicked "Debug" and JIT Debugger was opened, it threw "FataExecutionEngineError" exception... What does it mean?